# Facebook data to DisplayObject in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, displayobject

Is it possible to convert facebook data (ex. user_pic) into a *DisplayObject* so I can be easier to manipulate? 
What I m trying to do is when users do **FacebookConnect** in my site to let them have the possibility to scale their image (like transform tool usage) before submit it in a gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It turns out that OP already has the image in a `UILoader`. In that case, you can access it using the `content` property of `UILoader`

```
var img:Bitmap = Bitmap(uiLoader.content);
var bitmapdata:BitmapData = img.bitmapData;
```

---

You can load the user picture to your SWF using a [Loader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html) object and manipulate it, provided the image is hosted in a sever that allows SWFs from your domain to access contents using appropriate `crossdomain.xml`.

If you know the location of policy file, call [Security.loadPoliCyFile](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile()) before loading image. Flash player will try to load it from the default location `/crossdomain.xml`

```
Security.loadPolicyFile(policy-file-url);

var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
ldr.load(new URLRequest(the-image-url);

function onError(e:Event):void
{
  trace(e);
}
function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  //this will fail if there is no crossdomain.xml file at
  //the image's originating server.
  var image:Bitmap = LoaderInfo(e.target).content as Bitmap;
  var bitmapData:BitmapData = image.bitmapData;
  //do whatever you want with the bitmap data here
  addChild(image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact is that I load data with the Facebook GetInfo method and store them in a variable like that: 
pUser.pic_big; I don't have the exact URL for each picture. I use a UILoader component to add the image on stage through the UILOader.source=pUser.pic_big method but I cannot scale it or transform it at runtime.

Comment: @dimitree if you already have it on stage, you can access it using `uiLoader.content`

Comment: This means can I transform it and save the new image in my server?